# Change the interior Colour of a specific cell range when I activate a checkbox and the value of the connected cell turns to True or "WAHR"

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table with repeating tasks that have to be completed for every case repeatedly. I already created a macros that automatically adds 6 rows on top of the table with the description of the individual steps that need to be done to fulfill one task and automatically inserted checkboxes for every step that are connected to the cell one step to the right next to them. U can see that in the Link.

Now I want to create another macros, where if one task gets completed (the checkbox gets activated) I want the backround of specific cells next to the cell where the value changes from True to false to get a green backround **(RGB: 198,224,180)**.
The problem is that my excel is german and automatically sets the value of the to the checkbox connected box to "WAHR" which means "TRUE" and "FALSCH" which means "False". So I dont really know how to deal with this. I already tried so many codes related to this topic and nothing works.

Here u can see the table

[image]

**I want e.g. the cells G3:I3 to turn green **(RGB: 198,224,180)** if the checkbox in H3 is activated and it says "WAHR" in I3.
Also the cells G4:I4 to turn green if the checkbox in H4 is activated and it says "WAHR" in I4... and so on.
Ultimately if the last row is checked I also want the big now orange square in J3 to turn green as well.**

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Conditional Formatting function for that purpose.

Mark the cells from Column I of your sheet, then click on `Home` -> `Conditional Formatting` and select `Classic` as style.

In the next window, select `Only format cells that contain` and underneath select `Specific text`. In the field on the right hand side, you can then add `WAHR` as the trigger text and chose a formatting rule in the field at the bottom of the window. That should solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you very much :) I know how I can do that manually I just want it to happen automatically in form of a macros as a VBA code so that others if they add a case they can just click a button so it automatically occurs and then activate the function that if u check the boxes in the newly created task the backround of the cells gets green

Comment: It will happen automatically if you select all cells in the given column and can be replicated through copy/paste format for new sheets. Hope that helps nonetheless.

Comment: I know but then only the cells in the column "I" change colour but I want also the cells in "G" and "H" to turn green if the checkbox gets enabled :/ For example if I check the box in H 3 then G3 turns green because WAHR triggers the green colour but what do I need to do, that H3 and G3 also turn green. Thank you very much